# How to use ListView from class1 in class2 in android project?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I was browsing android forums on the internet and this is the place I find most acurate and professional answers to questions regarding Android.

I'm learning programming for Android and I'm working on one application.
I have implemented SQLite database with read and write, shwoing data in EditBoxes and similar things, but I can't implement ListView.

I have some example with ListView showing data from database.
I have managed to adapt that to show data from my database and it works as separate application.

My question is:
How can I add that modified example to my aplication?

That example has class:

```
public class DataListView extends ListActivity
```

and it's using another class for database access from my application:

```
public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

But, my own application has following class:

```
public class MyWorkActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

How can I call and use DataListView class in my own project?

Please help me, because I'm working on this ListView for over one week with no progress.

This is my main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/honeycomb2"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="9" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="6" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblVrijemDolaska"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblVrijemeDolaska"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <requestFocus />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblVrijemeOdlaska"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lblVrijemeOdlaska"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVrijemeDolaska"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="#00ccff"
            android:shadowDx="2"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="Vr. dolaska"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVrijemeOdlaska"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="#00ccff"
            android:shadowDx="2"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="Vr. odlaska"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" > 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDorucak3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/lblDorucak3" />    

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPauza3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/lblPauza3" />

    </TableRow>

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="9"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtDorucak3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="1"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblRazmak"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="             " />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtPauza3"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_span="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </TableRow>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDodaj"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="61dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dodaj"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:text="@string/btnDodaj" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnIzbrisi"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
            android:background="@drawable/izbrisi"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:text="@string/btnIzbrisi" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewDatabase"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvZaBazu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="5sp" >

    </ListView>

</TableLayout>
```

And this is ListView example that works with my database as separate app but nt in my project:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.saigmn.DatabaseManager.DatabaseInfo;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class DataListView extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
private SQLiteDatabase newDB;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    openAndQueryDatabase();

    displayResultList();


}
private void displayResultList() {
    //TextView tView = new TextView(this);
    //tView.setText("This data is retrieved from the database and only 4 " +
            //"of the results are displayed");
    //getListView().addHeaderView(tView);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}
private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
    try {

        newDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseInfo.IME_BAZE, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseInfo.IME_TABELE, null);

        if (c !=null && c.getCount() > 0) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                int Column1 = c.getColumnIndex("datum");
                int Column2 = c.getColumnIndex("dolazak");
                int Column3 = c.getColumnIndex("odlazak");
                int Column4 = c.getColumnIndex("r_vrijeme");
                do {


                    String datum = c.getString(Column1);
                    String dolazak = c.getString(Column2);
                    String odlazak = c.getString(Column3);
                    String r_vrijeme = c.getString(Column4);
                    results.add(datum + " * " + dolazak + " * " + odlazak + " -> " + r_vrijeme);

                }while (c.moveToNext());

        }           
    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Nije moguće kreirati ili otvoriti bazu");
    } finally {
        if (newDB != null) 
            //newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + DatabaseInfo.IME_TABELE);
            newDB.close();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing onClick listener in MyWorkActivity... so u have clickable objects..
on clicking one of the buttons.. you can make list view appear in your screen..in yourMyWorkActivity you have this part..

```
 button.SetOnClickListener(this);
OnclickListener(View v)
{
switch(v.getGetId());
{
  case R.id.x:<--- some button.. on clicking which listview should appear

Intent i=new Intent(MyWorkActivity.this,DataListView.class)
  startActivity(i);
   // by using these lines your application will display the datalistview activity you created..

}
 }

}
```

Comment: That's a quick answer, but I have layout for picking some tiem of arrival and time of departure and button for calculatiing time ddiference and adding data to database. Below I want to have ListView with all data from database so user can press on item and edit it or delete it. ListView must bi shown automatically with layout. Ihave managed to do that with TextView but I can't press on item.

Comment: ok.. post the xml file in which you have textview and listview together.. you need to set few values to not focusable..

Comment: I have posted main.xml and DataListView.java which is working as separate app but I can't include it in my project.